# Show text component in two lines if there is enough space at the above line

Tags: react-native

I'm using Text components to show the texts like below.

[Text] [Text] [Text] ...

The problem is that I have some text contents that start with ';' ',' or '.'

I don't want those to appear at the first part of each line.

So for example: (ignore [], [] means Text component)

3. [And] [God said][, let there] [be light]

   [: and there] [was] [light][.]

To

3. [And] [God said][, let there] [be light][: and

   there] [was] [light][.]

How can I place that [: and there] text component in two lines if there is enough space to show some part of the text? (e.g: ": and")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited Answer**

Placing the components one followed by the other inside a nested text component will result desired behavior, as shown in the first example of React-Native documentation: [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text).

```
<Text>
    <Text>
        {text1}
    </Text>
    <Text>
        {text2}
    </Text>
</Text>
```

---

**previous but not desired solution - included separating strings:**
(leaving it here in case that answer will help in similar-but-not-exact situations)

I would separate `[: and there]` into two text components (since they are two separated text components in my opinion) one is `[: and]` or `[:]` and the second is the rest. 
However, if in your app there is some logic you want that relates both separated components into one component, use some variable to save that information. Lets say like `compID` or something like that.

So it will look like:

```
id=0  id=1       id=2          id=3      id=4
[And] [God said][, let there] [be light][: and]

id=4    id=5  id=6   id=7
[there] [was] [light][.]
```

Comment: yeah there is some logic and those data coming from web api which is already pre-processed. 
I can force split them by space, but at the moment just want to solve this problem without split the texts if possible

Comment: Can you share the code with the order of the text components? Because Text Component followed by Text Component basically has that behavior you are looking for (if there is enough space, it prints the text over two lines)

Comment: Take a look at the first example.. If i got you right, this is exactly what you want: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for, will you please edit your answer with that link so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: Great :) so ill add it to my answer so it would be accepted. Glad it helped.

Comment: Please update your answer with that link so that this could helpful for the others. :)